# Python pyserial communication WindowsError(5)

Tags: python, serial-port, arduino, pyserial

I'm using pyserial to connect my python code with an arduino. As I run my python code, I keep getting this error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 66, in open
    raise SerialException("could not open port %r: %r" % (self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
SerialException: could not open port 'COM3': WindowsError(5, 'Access is denied.')
```

Here's my code:

```
import serial
port = 2
class arduino:

    def __init__(self):
        self.ser = serial.Serial(port, 9600)
        self.port = port

    def read(self):

        x = self.ser.read(100)
        self.ser.flush()
        return x

    def close(self):

        ser.close()


glove = arduino()
print(glove.read())
glove.close()
```

I have my arduino connected to COM3, and the arduino IDE is closed, so the error is definitely not cause by interference with the arduino serial interface. I'm the administrator so I don't think the problem is that I don't have administrative privileges.

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Thanks,

Dhruv

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `open()`

add this method, and use it before read:

```
def OpenPort(self):

    try:
        self.sSerial.open()
    except SerialException, e:
        raise e
```

One more thing you don't need to `self.ser.flush()` after reading the input Q of the serial port, since it's empty after the read command.

Comment: I fixed that, thanks. I'm still having the same error when I run the program though. Maybe it's not an issue with the code?

Comment: Are you sure the com is not opened by another application?

Comment: Well the only other application that I know could be using the com is the Arduino IDE, but I checked...and it isn't :(

Comment: Looks like it was just a glitch in my computer... I restarted it and now it works fine. Thanks for the help though!